# React Cloudinary Video not playing in iOS

Tags: reactjs, video, gif, mp4, cloudinary

I currently try to implement a video element to my react application.
It should be an image at the beginning and when you hover on it, it should play the image.
Unfortunately for iOS my solution will not work.

I tried several things, but it will not play the video altough I added "autoPlay, playsinline"

To make my question not to long I will only add one of my solutions for now.
But I can say I also tried it without the cloudinary image and video elements and it was the same result

**Here one of my solutions I used Video and Image cloudinary element:**

```
....

handleMouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({
      image: `${this.props.image}_mp4`,
      disabled: true,
    })
  };

handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({
      image: `${this.props.image}_image`,
      disabled: false,
    })
  };

render() {
  return(
    <Card className="mobile-project-card" text="white" onMouseOver={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseLeave}>
      <Image hidden={this.state.disabled} className="card-img " cloudName={process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUDNAME} publicId={`${this.props.image}_image`} alt={`${this.props.name} image`}>
        <Transformation quality="auto" fetchFormat="auto" width="450" crop="scale" />
      </Image>
      <Video ref={this.vidRef} hidden={!this.state.disabled} className="card-img" cloudName={process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUDNAME} publicId={`${this.props.image}_mp4`} alt={`${this.props.name} image`} playsInline muted loop autoPlay >
        <Transformation quality="auto" fetchFormat="auto"/>
      </Video>

....
```

Hope somebody can tell me what's missing.
If you need more explanation please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using just a `<Video>` element? My suggestion is as follows - Omit the `<Image>` element and use only a (non-hidden) `<Video>` element with a poster image set to the desired image. Then, use the `onMouseEnter` attribute to play the video -

```
<Video ref={this.vidRef} 
  className="card-img" 
  cloudName={process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUDNAME} 
  publicId={`${this.props.image}_mp4`} 
  alt={`${this.props.name} image`} 
  muted loop 
  poster="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg" //url of the desired image
  onMouseEnter={ event => event.target.play() }
  onMouseLeave={ event => event.target.pause() }
  >
  <Transformation quality="auto" fetchFormat="auto"/>
</Video>
```

You can use this as a reference -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/cloudinary-react-video-poster?file=index.js

Comment: When I do this, nothing happens. 
it just shows the poster image.